# Does a photon see a 0-D universe?

Tags: special-relativity, mass

For a massless particle the spacetime interval between its point of emission and point of absorption is zero: the two points coincide. From the vantage point of such a particle space-time has reduced to a single point.

In the Standard Model, *all* particles start with zero mass, so does this suggest that our familiar 4-D spacetime is a consequence of the Higgs field or some similar mechanism by which mass is acquired?

Note: if you believe the large-scale 4D structure of spacetime is a pre-existing given, this question makes little sense. In a relational view, where spacetime emerges out of event relationships, then the question suggests that a universe comprised solely of massless particles would have a fundamentally different event-structure.

Comment: Τwo events separated by a time-like interval lie on a 1-D line but it doesn't mean that a particle's space-time has reduced to a 1-D line.

Comment: We're talking about a light-like interval here. Although the 'line' at 45 degrees on a Minkowski diagram *looks like a line* it's not really because of the non-Euclidean metric: all the 'points' on that line are identified within the reference frame of a lightlike object.

Comment: Those points are not identified. There is a topological metric, which tells you which points are the same, so that all physical values are the same at those points, and then there is a physical notion of distance which is also called a metric. A week ago, I would have said the particle can't have a point of view, because it's infinite time dilation means that it can't do any computation. But I just learned that massless particles can decay.

Comment: Note to OP: Physics is supposed to give predictions testable by infinitely  advanced beings. In other words, no prediction of physics is such that the laws of physics prevent it from being verified. Thus, we cannot 'step into the POV of a photon', even hypothetically, as special relativity forbids any measiring device from piggybacking a photon.

Comment: @Manishearth: What is to prevent a hypothetical measuring device made of photons that interact via loop diagrams?

Answer (score 2):

Per special relativity, no human measurement device can ever reach the speed of light, and thus we can never test what the universe "looks" like in the eyes of photons. In other words, the question of what light would see is unfalsifiable and thus not a scientific question.

And if you force Lorentz transformation onto the frame of photons, you will get a lot of contradictory conclusions. For example, an object is moving at speed $v$ in some normal frame. Then in the frame of a photon that moves in opposite direction, the object is moving at speed
$$\frac{v+c}{1+\frac{vc}{c^2}}=c.$$

According to the invariance of speed of light, the object must be moving at speed of light in any frame, which contradicts our premise that it is moving at speed $v$ in some normal frame.

Moreover, in general relativity, the spatial and temporal component of a four-vector as measured by an observer is directly related to the four-velocity of the said observer. For instance, energy $E$ is the temporal component of four-momentum, as in 
$$E=-p^\mu U_\mu.$$
Since light-like paths does not have a well-defined four-velocity, you can also see it makes no sense for a photon to "see" or measure anything.

> For a massless particle the spacetime interval between its point of emission and point of absorption is zero: the two points coincide.

This is not true. The distance in Lorentzian manifold is not postively definite, so zero distance in no way implies the same point.

Comment: What a photon does "see" is funny on the semantics level already :=). This reminds me of the "looking rays" one of my daughters tried to convince me of when she was about 3 or 4.

Comment: What about a measurement device made entirely of photons? It would be able to move at the speed of light, and interact via loop diagrams.

Comment: @Georg Didn't the old Greeks postulate looking rays? (Some ray tracers actually work that way :-) ). Although ultimately wrong, I guess it was a nice exercise in scientific thinking to make this hypothesis and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the photon world as in all 4 spacetime dimensions with length=null fully is in a relativistic Einstein tradition. This solves the quantum-mechanical duality problem as

"photon is a partical" = "a wave in a one point spacetime"

Thus entanglement of two photons can be said ever is local and hence interpretable in classical ways without spooky quantum-mechanics.

But I must admit I worry if this locality holds for very long distances of billion light years where dark energy comes to my mind :/

Answer (score -1):

We see a 3D universe with help of photons.

The "gauge nature" of all particles is an incredible stretch which does not work itself at all. Higgs "mechanism" is a patch of this stretch and mass of Higgs needs another "mechanism" to be explained.

I think starting from phenomenological masses is the only healthy physical way of giving masses to all particles and bodies. Some masses can be calculated from others then.

Comment: Not an answer but a confession of hopelessness following your unhappiness with the Higgs mechanism!

Comment: No unhappiness, just a common sense.

Comment: -1 Higgs mechanism is just superconductivity, and gauge nature of all particles is not a stretch, but an experimental fact.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: And how about bare particles and their strong interactions? They are also "needed" in theory to describe experimental facts. It is they who should be considered as the true bricks of nature. And mass of Higgs is certainly given by God.

Comment: @Vladimir: the mass of the Higgs is fine-tuned in many models, but it can be naturally small in technicolor models. We'll find out what it is soon enough. As for "bare particles", these are just a mathematical artifact of 1950s approaches to renormalization. The modern approach, due to Wilson, is free of paradoxes, and is as easy to understand as the scaling in a second order phase transition.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: So you recognize that QED had been constructed without knowing the correct physics and "understanding" came later, from Wilson. That's the problem - finding "interpretations" and "understanding" **after**. It cannot be a healthy way of doing theoretical physics; it is blind guesses, counting on luck and stop-gaps to "doctor numbers", and it does no work without fail. Remember quantum gravity and other non-renormalizable theories.

Comment: Concerning Wilson, no one QFT was designed as an effective theory, it was not foreseen at the beginning, so the Wilson's interpretations is a last resort for failed attempts to build a theory without solid physical background. If you want to see to what extent Wilson is irrelevant, read my popular explanation here: http://www.science20.com/qed_reformulation_feasible/blog/ultimate_explanation_renormalizations-81791

Comment: Why Higgs mass may be fine tuned but the other masses may not? Who prevents us from writing the right known masses in our equations?

Comment: @Vladimir--- please read Wilson, not the nonsense people nowadays say about Wilson! Wilson did not do "effective field theory", he did full blown continuum limit field theory, and he did it the right way, by noting that statistical systems have a continuum limit at a second order phase transition, and quantum path integrals may be defined by the exact same limit. Wilson's approach is only a rigorous version of the original renormalization, which wasn't wrong, just incomplete (and people, certainly Gell-Mann, possibly Stuckelberg, had an inkling of Wilsonian ideas even then)

Comment: @Vladimir: Mass terms are forbidden in the standard model because they flip right and left handed particles, and the right and left handed particles have different gauge charges. So if you want to flip them, you have to have charged particles in the vacuum to pick up when you do the flip. This charged-condensate is the Higgs mechanism. It is inelegant that the Higgs has a tunable mass, it should come out naturally, like the mass of the proton, which is not tuned at all, but due to the slow logarithmic renormalization group running of QCD.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: Ron, if you write a model and you believe in it, you start to "interpret" it. QFT is a model, and if you want to keep it, you do everything to talk yourself into accepting it. Thus were bare particles "discovered". The same is valid for Wilson's interpretation of the same old QFT model - it is an attempt to give a physical meaning to the cut-off. Then the renormalizations look better "justified". But there may be other models, without corrections to constants, without cut-offs, without referring to unknown stuff serving exclusively to save a failed theory face.

Comment: @Vladimir--- I do not need to persuade myself quantum field theory is well defined, it is manifestly, self-evidently, obviously ok. There is no cutoff for quantum field theories like QCD, you can just take the continuum limit. All continuum objects, including the solutions of Newton's differential equations, are defined by a limiting process. In Quantum field theory, the limit is slightly more delicate, in that the parameters need to be tuned right to make the limit work.

Comment: @Ron: It's a handwaving argument. The evil is in the details. Newton equations are not plagued with non-physical solutions at all. Electrodynamics ones are. Despite that we construct QFT by analogy with electrodynamics. Why to introduce in QFT something and then get rid of it with help of renormalizations? OK, I see you underestimate the history of the difficulties and consider QFT as problemless. And I consider it problematic with conceptual problems. Finally, QFT is about occupation number dynamics. Some states are populated during interactions, some depleted. Why it cannot be done simpler?

Comment: I do not underestimate the historical difficulties, I just properly estimate Kenneth Wilson, who solved this problem in 1974 and won a Nobel prize. To define a quantum field theory without mathematical ill-defined steps, you discretize its Euclidean version, look for a second-order phase transition as you vary the parameters in the discretization, and zoom in to a scaling limit at the critical point. This solves (PT invariant, bosonic) quantum fields and second order phase transitions both at the same time.

Comment: Ill defined are physical ideas like self-action, for example. Math works fine and shows you what you get from your ideas. The critical point is our physical ideas - what is what and how all that exchanges energy-momentum with each other.